# Помогите с шифром A1Z26

Tags: python

Мне надо написать шифр A1Z26 в питоне. Вот что у меня получилось:

```
def shifr_A1Z26(message, key):
    result=[]

    alf = ['','А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е','Ё','Ж','З','И','Й','К','Л','М','Н','О','П','Р','С','Т',
           'У','Ф','Х','Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Ъ','Ы','Ь','Э','Ю','Я']

    alf2 = ['','а','б','в','г','д','е','ё','ж','з','и','й','к','л','м','н','о','п','р','с','т',
            'у','ф','х','ц','ч','ш','щ','ъ','ы','ь','э','ю','я']

    for txt in message:
        if txt.isupper() and txt!=' ':
            mes=alf.index(txt)
            mes=str(mes)
            result.append(mes)
            result.append('-')
        elif txt==' ':
            result
        else:
            if txt != ' ':
                mes=alf2.index(txt)
                mes=str(mes)
                result.append(mes)
                result.append('-')
            else:
                result.append(' ')

    return ''.join(result)
```

Но когда я ввожу какое-то слово, у меня после крайнего числа стоит лишнее тире(программа изъята из целой программы, поэтому написана в функции, можете без неё). Помогите решить проблему

Answer (score 0):

```
def shifr_A1Z26(message, key):
    result=[]

    alf = ['','А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е','Ё','Ж','З','И','Й','К','Л','М','Н','О','П','Р','С','Т',
           'У','Ф','Х','Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Ъ','Ы','Ь','Э','Ю','Я']

    alf2 = ['','а','б','в','г','д','е','ё','ж','з','и','й','к','л','м','н','о','п','р','с','т',
            'у','ф','х','ц','ч','ш','щ','ъ','ы','ь','э','ю','я']

    for txt in message:
        if txt.isupper() and txt!=' ':
            mes=alf.index(txt)
            mes=str(mes)
            result.append(mes)
            result.append('-')
        elif txt==' ':
            result
        else:
            if txt != ' ':
                mes=alf2.index(txt)
                mes=str(mes)
                result.append(mes)
                result.append('-')
            else:
                result.append(' ')
    del(result[-1])
    print(result)
    return ''.join(result)

shifr_A1Z26('Привет', 1)
```

del yдаляет последний индекс

Comment: но это только для одного слова?

Comment: или я могу ввести любое?

Comment: я сейчас попробовал вашу программу, для одного слова оно работает, но когда я ставлю пробел, появляется знак тире

Comment: Тогда делайте обход по циклy for ... in ...